# Python uniform() alternative in Java/Groovy (generate random float)

Tags: java, python, random, groovy

How can I generate random float in range as this is made in Python using `uniform()` method?
Example is [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_uniform.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python: r = uniform(x,y) returns x <= r < y

So, In java, use:

```
 r = x + (y-x) *  Math.random();
```

Answer (score 1):

The Java `Random` class has a `nextFloat()` method:

> public float nextFloat()
>
> Returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed float value between 0.0 and 1.0 from this random number generator's sequence.

So, just scale affinely:

```
public float uniform(float lower, float upper, Random randomSrc) {
    return lower + (upper - lower) * randomSrc.nextFloat();
}
```

There are `double` versions too.